# ResourceNotFoundException how to debug?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got couple reports on Market about this exception. There is no reference to where it happens in my app and majority of users do not have thit issue. How do I debug something like that? This is NOT exception I get from all devices. Just one specific device might report it.

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x109005d
 at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:892)
 at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1869)
 at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:731)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:318)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2451)
 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2506)
 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:1626)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2165)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1672)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: check R.java to find out for which control ,compiler created Resource ID #0x109005d

Comment: Just checked - didn't find. There was similar exception and I found ID in R.java - that was just a string. All my string inside resources (app is localized)

Comment: then it is something related to parsing xml from reource , just check where you used xml parsing in resource

Comment: Project => Clean => choose your project => OK .

Comment: Do the comments include any specific information about phone model or platform version?

Comment: I know one happened on Galaxy Tab from a comment

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is some resource that is defined in a specific folder and is not in a less specific folder? Like, you defined a drawable X in the folder drawable-land and not in the drawable-port? You should double-check your specific folders for resources that are not in other folders

Answer (score 0):

By chance do you use this resource: `com.android.internal.R.layout.search_dropdown_item_icons_2line` ? Since it is an internal package, maybe not all implementations contain it (or not each API level), or contain it but with different resource identifier.

Comment: Nope. I'm not using any of the android resources. All artwork, strings, etc is my own.